# loop error trying to verify valid input to double in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, scanf

I'm trying to verify that a character input to a double variable is of the right data type.

```
double number = 0;
int validCheck = 0;
char another = 'y';

while(another == 'y')
{
    cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
    validCheck = scanf("%lf", &number);

    while (validCheck !=1)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid input, please enter a number: ";
        validCheck = scanf("%lf", &number);
    }
```

When I compile this, it works fine provided I give a valid input, and an invalid input does put it into the while loop, but rather than checking for another input, it just spams my console with "Invalid input, please enter a number:" without even asking for a new input. What am I missing?

Comment: try with the following insertion after while(): fflush(stdin);

Comment: This is really a C question.  A couple of cout statements do not make it C++.  facunvd is correct, you have to flush the input.

Comment: @facunvd -- doing a fflush on stdin is undefined.  Offering that as solution is terrible advice.  See 12.26a of the C FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid input remains in the input buffer, so the `scanf` is always presented with the same malformed input. You need to clear the input buffer, e.g.

```
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: Took me a bit to see what you're doing ... I think. This sets an integer c, and it pulls from the buffer until the buffer is a new line or end of file?

Comment: Right. It's intended to empty the buffer, since the terminal sends the input to the process after a newline has been entered, the emptying loop stops if it finds one. `c` has to be an `Int` and not a `char` to be able to test for `EOF`. Of course, if an `EOF` condition is actually encountered, you can't read anything from `stdin` anymore, so then you should `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` or something to not be trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: That worked great, and I'm OK with using it now that I understand it. Though ... from talking to my instructor I think I'd have been better off using a string and checking to see if it was an int ...

On the other hand, our instructions were to "just assume the user will input a number" this has all been a masochistic exercise for myself ;) Thanks for your help!